# tkinter Text Widget duplicating when progress bar displayed

Tags: text, tkinter, widget, duplicates

I have an app that displays progress messages via a Text widget, so that it will scroll if there are many lines. It also displays a 'Task' Progress Bar for each individual step, and a different 'Total' Progress Bar for the total completion.

My situation is that I want to have the progress bars not displayed if they have no 'content'. So neither of them at the start and end of the processing. The 'Total' progress bar would display once the first step is complete, and the 'Task' progress bar would be displayed if the task is long enough to warrant it.

It's a big app but here is a shortened version of what I have (still long though).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8

# Try to work with older version of Python
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import Tkinter.ttk as ttk
else:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
#============================================================================
#   MAIN CLASS
class Main(tk.Frame):
    """ Main processing
    """
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs)

        self.root = root

        self.MW_f = tk.Frame(self.root)

        # Progress Messages
        self.PM_prog_msgs_lf_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.PM_prog_msgs_lf = tk.LabelFrame(self.MW_f,
                                             text=' Progress Messages: ',
                                             relief='sunken')

        # Progress Message text widget
        self.PM_prog_msgs_max_frame_height = 6
        self.PM_prog_msgs_line_count = 0
        self.PM_prog_msgs_t = tk.Text(self.PM_prog_msgs_lf, height=self.PM_prog_msgs_max_frame_height, width=100)
        self.PM_prog_msgs_t_vbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.PM_prog_msgs_lf,
                                   orient='vertical', command=self.PM_prog_msgs_t.yview)
        self.PM_prog_msgs_t['yscrollcommand'] = self.PM_prog_msgs_t_vbar.set

        self.PM_prog_msgs_t['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.PM_prog_msgs_t['border'] = 3

        self.PM_task_progbar_var = tk.IntVar()
        self.PM_task_progbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.MW_f,
                                               orient='horizontal',
                                               mode='indeterminate',
                                               variable=self.PM_task_progbar_var)

        self.PM_progbar_var = tk.IntVar()
        self.PM_progbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.MW_f,
                                          orient='horizontal',
                                          mode='determinate',
                                          variable=self.PM_progbar_var,
                                          maximum=4)

        self.PM_go_btn = tk.Button(self.MW_f,
                                  text='Go',
                                  command=self.action_go_btn)

        self.MW_stsbar_tvar = tk.StringVar()
        self.MW_stsbar = tk.Label(self.MW_f,
                                  textvariable=self.MW_stsbar_tvar)

        # Grid the widgets
        self.MW_f.grid()
        MW_grid_row = 0

        # Place into MW_f
        self.PM_prog_msgs_lf.grid(row=MW_grid_row, column=0, sticky='we')
        # Place into PM_prog_msgs_lf
        self.PM_prog_msgs_t.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.PM_prog_msgs_t_vbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

        MW_grid_row += 1
        self.PM_task_progbar_row = MW_grid_row
        self.PM_task_progbar.grid(row=self.PM_task_progbar_row, sticky='we')
        MW_grid_row += 1
        self.PM_progbar_row = MW_grid_row
        self.PM_progbar.grid(row=self.PM_progbar_row, sticky='we')
        MW_grid_row += 1
        self.MW_stsbar.grid(row=MW_grid_row, sticky='w')
        MW_grid_row += 1
        self.PM_go_btn.grid(row=MW_grid_row)

        # Remove these until needed
        self.PM_task_progbar.grid_remove()
        self.PM_progbar.grid_remove()
        self.PM_prog_msgs_t_vbar.grid_remove()

        self.MW_dsp_stsbar_msg('Processing: Refer to progress message pane for more details')

#   Window Displays Now
#=========================================================================================
#   Functions used by window
    def action_go_btn(self):
        """
        """
        msg = 'Line 1\nLine 2'
        self.PM_dsp_prog_msgs(msg, 2)
        self.PM_task_progbar_update()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.PM_progbar_update()

        self.PM_dsp_prog_msgs('Line 3', 1)
        self.PM_task_progbar_update()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.PM_progbar_update()

        msg = 'Line 4\nLine 5\nLine 6'
        self.PM_dsp_prog_msgs(msg, 3)
        self.PM_task_progbar_update()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.PM_progbar_update()

        msg = 'Line 7\nLine 8\nLine 9'
        self.PM_dsp_prog_msgs(msg, 3)
        self.PM_task_progbar_update()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.PM_progbar_update()
        self.PM_progbar.grid_remove()

        return

    def MW_dsp_stsbar_msg(self, msg):
        """
        """
        # Display the statusbar
        self.MW_stsbar_tvar.set(msg)

        return

    def PM_dsp_prog_msgs(self, msg, lines):
        """
        """
        # Populate the message
        self.PM_prog_msgs_t['state'] = 'normal'
        self.PM_prog_msgs_t.insert(tk.END, ('\n'+msg))
        self.PM_prog_msgs_t['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.root.update_idletasks()

        self.PM_prog_msgs_line_count += lines

        # If its time display the vert scroll bar
        if not self.PM_prog_msgs_t_vbar.winfo_viewable():
            if self.PM_prog_msgs_line_count > self.PM_prog_msgs_max_frame_height:
                self.PM_prog_msgs_t_vbar.grid(row=0, column=1)
                self.root.update_idletasks()

        # Show the last line.
        self.PM_prog_msgs_t.see(tk.END)

        self.root.update_idletasks()

        return

    def PM_progbar_update(self):
        """
        """
        if not self.PM_progbar.winfo_viewable():
            self.PM_progbar.grid()

        # Remove the task progbar
        self.PM_task_progbar.stop()
        self.PM_task_progbar.grid_remove()

        # Increment the progbar
        self.PM_progbar.step()

        self.root.update_idletasks()

        return

    def PM_task_progbar_update(self):
        """
        """
        # Display if not already displayed
        if not self.PM_task_progbar.winfo_viewable():
            self.PM_task_progbar.grid()
            self.root.update_idletasks()

        # Step
        self.PM_task_progbar.start()

        self.root.update_idletasks()

        return

#   MAIN (MAIN) ===========================================================================
def main():
    """ Run the app
    """
    # # Create the screen instance and name it
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
    root.quit()

#   MAIN (STARTUP) ====================================================
#   This next line runs the app as a standalone app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run the function name main()
    main()
```

What happens is when the 'Task' progress bar is displayed the 'Progress Messages' label frame is duplicated, and moved down one line (see the screen shot)

Sorry, I cannot attach the screen shot. This is a text version of the screenshot!

> - Progress Messages ---------------------------------------
> - Progress Messages ---------------------------------------
>
>   Message Step 1
>
> [Task Progress Bar                                         ]
>
> [Total Progress Bar                                        ]

The display remains this way until the end. Even when the 'Task' progress bar is removed the duplication remains. The display does not add a third version when the 'Total' progress bar is displayed though.

Everything corrects itself at the end when both progress bars are removed.

All the widgets are gridded to the correct frame and the row/column seems to be correct, so where do I look to correct this.

Many thanks, and sorry this is all so long.

MacBookPro (2007), python 3.4, tkinter 8.5

Comment: _It's a big app but here is a shortened version of what I have (still long though)_  The problem is not widget placement, but that you have 100s of lines of untested code. You don't  specify row or column to grid() in the update functions so they are added where ever the default is, which explains the "third version" not appearing.  It is there but something is layered on top of it.  The label frame moving down is caused by a row above it appearing because a widget has been placed in the row, moving the others down, because that is the default row and column that grid uses.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, but even if I save the row number used in the original gridding, and then use it during the update functions, I still get the duplicating. Extra lines of code is not the issue as I follow this coding line by line by debug. There is no other coding that grids anything else to the top of the frame.

Comment: So my latest experimentation shows that if I put all widgets into root, instead of a frame, when the FIRST progress bar is displayed, a new window heading is displayed, complete with its own set of buttons. Using grid_info(), all the rows and columns are where they need to be.

Comment: So if anyone is following this, even if I re-grid the entire window, I still get the duplication. However, if I remove the label frame which contains the text widget, everything works fine!